# Can't upload file attachments for VSTS Git .NET

Tags: c#, git, stream, azure-devops, pull-request

I'm having trouble uploading attachments using the VSTS .NET Client. Here is the error I would get:

> "Invalid file type. Allowed extensions are PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG, DOCX,
>   PPTX, XLSX, TXT, PDF, ZIP, GZ, LYR, MOV, MP4"

Here is my code:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(uri, pat);
GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Test.txt");

var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
var result = gitClient.CreateAttachmentAsync(fileStream, "testFile", repository.Id, pullRequest.PullRequestId).Result;
```

Any help or suggestion would be great!

Comment: Do you want to add `Test.txt` into a pull request comment or add `Test.txt` into git repo? And it seems `gitClient` has no such method `CreateAttachmentAsync`.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I want to add it to the pull request and that method is under GitHttpClientBase class

Comment: Can you share the entire code here?